# Adding a class to a div when the user has scrolled down an X amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to add/remove a class depending on which direction a user is scrolling. As of now, the class gets added as soon as the user scrolls down from point `0`. I would like the class to get added when the user scrolls down at least an X amount of pixels. I tried changing the `0` in the `lastScrollTop` variable but it didn't work. Can someone help me out?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       $('#masthead').addClass('unpinned');
   } else {
      $('#masthead').removeClass('unpinned');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Note: The code is set so that the class gets removed as soon as the user starts scrolling back up from any point. I would like to keep this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
var scrollLimit = 600;
var lastScrollTop;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(st,lastScrollTop);
   if (st > scrollLimit){
       $('#masthead').addClass('unpinned');
   } 
   if(st < lastScrollTop){
      $('#masthead').removeClass('unpinned');
   }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1L4Lhsp1/4/)

Comment: The original code is set so that as soon as the user scrolls up from any point, the class gets removed. Your code shows that the class gets added at the `600` mark, but when I start scrolling back up, the class doesn't get removed.

Comment: In the demo, the class doesn't get removed as soon as I scroll up. [Here is an example of how it's supposed to function.](http://www.dantobinsmith.com/featured/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wrap that jQuery addClass call in an if statement checking the size of st like this:

```
    if(st > 2000) $('#masthead').addClass('unpinned');
```

That will only add the class once the user has scrolled down 2000px.